# When is this sum of perfect powers bounded

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

For any positive integers $n,d$, let

$$
A_d(n)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^{2d}}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}
$$

It is easy to see (and well-known) that for fixed $d$, $A_d(.)$ is
a polynomial of degree $2d-2$. Then we can speak of $A_d(x)$ for any
$x\in{\mathbb R}$, not just the positive integers.

Is it known for which real numbers $x$ the sequence $(A_d(x))_{d\geq 1}$ is
bounded ?

This question was also asked on [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178189/when-is-this-sum-of-perfect-powers-bounded).

Comment: I don't know, but it seems the closed interval [-1,1] should be the answer.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger I played with it a bit, and for most rationals (including those in [-1,1]) it seems to grow quite rapidly.

Comment: Played with it some more - actually it seems that $\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)A_d(x)}{A_d(-1/4)}$ converges quite nicely to $\frac3{32}\sin(2\pi x)$; in particular, $A_d(x)/A_d(-1/4)$ stays bounded for every $x$ (while $A_d(-1/4)$ grows very rapidly)

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_d(n)=n(n+1)(2n+1)A_d(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nk^{2d}$, then numerical evidence suggests
$$
\lim_{d\to\infty}\frac{4^{2d+1}}{E_{2d}}S_d(x)=\sin(2\pi x),
$$
where $E$ are the Euler numbers. Using [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) this reduces to
$$
2\lim_{d\to\infty}4^{2d-k}\frac{B_{2(d-k)}}{(2(d-k))!}/\frac{E_{2d}}{(2d)!}=(-1)^{k+1}\pi^{2k+1}
$$
where $B$ are the Bernoulii numbers.

The last equality must be well known although I do not have a reference (or proof).

Has been [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188054/214353) on math.SE.

It turns out that $A_d(x)$ is unbounded at all $x$ except for $A_d(1/2)=A_d(-3/2)=\frac1{3\cdot2^{2d-1}}$ and $A_d(1)=A_d(-2)=1/6$.

Comment: The second limit follows from the asymptotics for the [Euler](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/581202/5531) and [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Asymptotic_approximation) numbers.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes I thought about using asymptotics but could not establish a rigorous argument since I do not know what is behind these $\sim$s...